# attempt to use array `A' in a scalar context awk error?

Tags: awk

I have some code below:

```
BEGIN{

FS= "|"
countA=CountB=0;

}

{

id=substr($2,1,1);
++file[id]




if ($3 == "P")
    {
   if(countB==0){
    for(dupes in B)
    print B[dupes] > "Bdupes.txt"
    }
}

else if(countA==0){
   for(dupes in A){
    print A[dupes] > "Adupes.txt"
    }
}

else if(countA==countB){
   i=1
    while(i<countA){

     printA[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
     printB[i] > "mixdupes.txt"

     }
}

if(A<B && A!=0){

   i=1
    while(i<(A+1)){
     printA[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
     printB[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
     }

   i=A+1
    while(i<(B+1)){
     print B[i]> "Bdupes.txt"


  if(id=="A"){
    A[1]=$0
    countA=1;
    countB=0;

    }

  else if (id=="B"){
    B[1]=$0
    countA=0;
    countB=1;
    }
  }
elseif ($3 == "C")
{

   if(id=="A"){
    countA++;
    A[countA]=$0
    }

else if(id=="B"){
   countB++;
    B[countB]=$0
    }

}
}
}
END{

for (file_id in file)
print file_id ":", file[file_id]

}
```

However I am getting the error:

```
   awk: testking123.awk:81: (FILENAME=sample.txt FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use array `A' in a scalar context
```

My input is this:

```
Name|ID (file A or File B)|DDStatus(Parent or Child)|ParentID
Jon|A4|U|
Bob|B5|U|
Amy|A1|P|
Amy|A2|C|A1
Amy|B1|C|A1
Gareth|A3|P|
Gareth|B2|C|A3
Gareth|B3|C|A3
Phil|A5|P|
Phil|B4|C|A5
Elaine|B6|P|
Elaine|B7|C|B6
```

& The expected out put would be:

ADupes.txt (Parents & Dupes(children) if both are from file A or just dupes if AAB)

```
Amy|A2|C|A1
```

BDupes.txt (Parents & Dupes(children) if both are from file B or just dupes if ABB)

```
Gareth|B3|C|A3
Elaine|B6|P|
Elaine|B7|C|B6
```

mixdupes.txt (Parents & Dupes(Children) from file A + B

```
Amy|A1|P|
Amy|B1|C|A1
Gareth|A3|P|
Gareth|B2|C|A3
Phil|A5|P|
Phil|B4|C|A5
```

Very new to coding in general so I am not sure what this error means and why I have got it. Not sure whether I have typed this out clear enough but hopefully I have. Thanks in advance!!!
Amy

Comment: Can you explain as well how you select the lines for `ADupes.txt`, `BDupes.txt` and `mixdupes.txt`?

Comment: I had added some info, hope you can understand it. Thanks

Comment: In your BDupes.txt why did you include `Elaine|B6|P` as well? When in ADupes.txt you didn't include the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lines like these:

```
 printA[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
 printB[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
```

Add spaces to them:

```
 print A[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
 print B[i] > "mixdupes.txt"
```

And there are two instances of that set.

Also about your error, it could be because you `A` and `B` in algorithmic expressions e.g.

```
    if (A < B && A != 0) {
        while (i < (A + 1)) {
        i = A + 1
        while (i < (B + 1)) {
```

Perhaps you mean `countA` and `countB`?

Comment: thanks I have added the spaces & the error is still coming up